# how to keep a python script running when I close putty

Tags: python, putty

I'm about to run an python script on Ubuntu on VPS. It's is machine learning training process so take huge time to train. How can I close putty without stopping that process.

Comment: Check out `nohup`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have two main choices:

1. Run the command with `nohup`. This will disassociate it from your session and let it continue running after you disconnect:

   ```
   nohup pythonScript.py
   ```

   Note that the stdout of the command will be appended to a file called `nohup.out` unless you redirect it (`nohup pythonScript.py > outfile`).
2. Use a screen multiplexer like `tmux`. This will let you disconnect from the remote machine but then, next time you connect, if you run `tmux attach` again, you will find yourself in exactly the same session. The command will still be running (it will continue running when you log out) and you will be able to see its stdout and stderr just as though you'd never logged out:

   ```
   tmux 
   pythonScript.py
   ```

   Once you've launched that, just close the PuTTY window. Then, connect again the next day, run `tmux attach` again and you're back where you started.

Comment: Alternatives to 1& 2:  1. `disown` 2. `screen`

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning `byobu`, a wrapper around tmux or screen.

Comment: `nohup python -u your_code.py &` and printout, log will be saved in "nohup.out " file

Comment: I don't think python scripts run that way without specifying `python` or `python3`

Comment: @PeDro of course they do. As long as they are properly written and have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) they will run just like any other script. You could simply try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

The [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview) tool, available for all Linux distros, supports this.

To install it, run `apt-get install screen` for deb-based Linux distros, or
`dnf install -y screen` or `yum install -y screen` for RPM-based ones.

To use:

`$ screen`

A new shell is started. In this shell, you can start your Python script.
Then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd>.
It will detach your terminal from the shell that is running your script.
Furthermore, the script is still running in it.

To see how your script is running, you can call `screen -r`.
This will reattach your terminal to the shell with the Python script you left running in background.

UPD: as Fox mentioned, screen works badly with systemd, but we can use systemd to start the script, like they say in [official example](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Examples).

For example, if your script is started by `/usr/bin/myPythonScript`, you can create Systemd unit file, like this.

`$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myPythonScript.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MyPythonScript

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myPythonScript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Than, you can start this script
`# systemctl daemon-reload`
`# systemctl start myPythonScript`

If you want to make this script started automatically on system start -

`# systemctl enable myPythonScript`

Anytime you can view how your script is running

`# systemctl status myPythonScript`

Ad you can review logs of your script

`# journalctl -u myPythonScript -e`

Comment: Note that `screen` does not exactly play nicely with `systemd` in its default configuration.  I don't know if Ubuntu uses `systemd`, but [the behavior and workaround](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394) might be worth mentioning in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Most processes can be fooled by redirecting its stdout, stderr, stdin (not all descriptors are always necessary to redirect) and using `&` control operator.

See that `ping example.com 1>/dev/null &` does the job.

Of course, some programs are more sophisticated and require such solutions as @terdon mentioned, but it's good to know and use what fits best.

EDIT: as written in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/463375) kills `systemd` processes on logout. Some versions of `systemd` kill processes on logout by default, others don't. This behavior can be changed by modifying /etc/systemd/logind.conf by setting the following option. As written, it may also solve some issues you may have with @terdon's solutions.

from `man logind.conf`:

> `KillUserProcesses=`
>
> Takes a boolean argument. Configures whether the processes of a user should be killed when the user logs out. If true, the scope unit corresponding to the session and all processes inside that scope will be terminated. If false, the scope is "abandoned", see systemd.scope(5), and processes are not killed. Defaults to "yes", but see the options `KillOnlyUsers=` and `KillExcludeUsers=` below.
>
> In addition to session processes, user process may run under the user manager unit user@.service. Depending on the linger settings, this may allow users to run processes independent of their login sessions. See the description of `enable-linger` in `loginctl`(1).
>
> Note that setting `KillUserProcesses=yes` will break tools like `screen`(1) and `tmux`(1), unless they are moved out of the session scope. See example in `systemd-run`(1).

Read linked answer to find out more.

Comment: This simply sends the process to the background. The OP wants to be able to disconnect from a remote ssh session and have the process continue. This won't help in that situation, exiting the remote session will stop the command even if it is in the background.

Comment: @terdon have you checked if my example works? I have checked and it works for *some* commands, as I have written in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and yes, I have seen that sometimes the command continues. I have, however, very often seen that the command stops so unless you can explain exactly what commands continue or provide a way of knowing in advance whether it will continue or not, this isn't very useful. In fact, the specific example you gave failed on a test I just ran connecting from my Arch to a remote Ubuntu system.

Comment: @terdon funny, I have checked this on local ArchLinux connecting to remote PLD. The only rule that works all the time is "does the program use `isatty()` and exits if it isn't?"

Comment: That might merit its own question. I know I used to always need nohup, and then at some point something changed and I sometimes didn't. I can't see how the isatty could be it though, if you exit the parent shell, that should also kill the child. But yes, sometimes it doesn't. I am guessing it must be configurable somehow.

Comment: On logging out (or rather, losing the terminal), the program gets the [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) signal, which, by default, terminates. Nothing in your answer solves that. And before you ask _"have you checked if my example works?"_, yes I have and it doesn't work for me.